# Get-MsalToken does not include audience claim in the token. How do i include audience claim in the token while using Get-MsalToken?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I use this powershell script to generate an azure AD jwt token. It is missing the audience claim. how do i include that?

```
$connectionDetails = @{
    'TenantId'    = '****'
    'ClientId'    = '****'
    'Interactive' = $true
    'Scopes' = ''
    'LoginHint' = '****'
}
$token = Get-MsalToken @connectionDetails

Write-Output $token
```

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Usually the value of **Scopes** is the `aud` claim in the token, how do you set **Scopes**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary comments are posted as answers.

As I said in the comments, usually, the value of the `scope` is the `aud` claim in the token. Because you did not set the `scope` in the script, the token you obtained has no `aud` claim.

So you must set the scope, for example:

`'Scopes' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'`